# Change option value when page reload using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown select like this:

```
<select>
<option>Select language</option>
<option value="en">english</option>
<option value="jp">japanese</option>
<option value="kr">korean</option>
</select>
```

using jQuery, when I refresh the page, I want the `option english` be selected. how can I do this?

Thanks
..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(function() {  // document ready
$('option[value=en]').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do: `$('select.yourClass').val('en');`

P.S. The `.yourClass` part is only needed if your `select` has a class.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {  // document ready
 $('SELECT').val('en');  // set to the OPTION value
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Isnt it simple?

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('select').val('en');});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put :

```
$('select').val('en');
```